# Making Windows Explorer distinctive (changing background color or file/folder icons) for specific folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, colors, icons

Is there a way to change the background color in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 when the current folder being displayed meets a certain condition?  Or is there a way I can change the icons of the files and folders within that folder so it's distinctive--similar to how Tortoise SVN does it for code checked out from a repository?

Why?

I'd like to do this for a deployment directory on a live server so users don't accidentally commit code to a certain environment.  Like myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature to control folder customization via Desktop.ini was greatly reduced in Vista, and more-so in 7.

There's are utilities around the net that purport to be able to do what you ask.

For example:

[Windows 7 Folder Background Changer](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-7-folder-background-changer-released):

> Windows 7 Folder Background Changer is a free tiny portable tool that allows you to change any folder’s background & text color in Windows 7/Vista.

and

[Ave's Vista Apps: Vista Folder Background](http://www.aveapps.com/folderbg.html)

Geared for Vista, but reports seem to indicate it work under 7 as well.

> In Vista, the ability to have custom backgrounds in explorer folders is gone. This small application makes folder backgrounds possible again.

Note: I've never used either, so YMMV. :)

Answer (score 1):

[Folder Marker Pro](http://www.foldermarker.com/folder-marker-pro.php) might help you.

[image]